# Running a Node.js application on GoDaddy forever

Tags: node.js, ssh, terminal, hosting, gnu-screen

I am running a Node.js application on my hosting. It's not shared hosting, I have dedicated server. I start my application from the command line (after SSH-ing) into the server:

1. Open a GNU screen
2. Build and run the application
3. Detach the GNU screen
4. Exit session

This was working perfectly in the last few weeks / month. But apparently there was maintenance on GoDaddy and the server has crashed and my screen died. This keeps happening at least 1-2 times per week. Restarting this process manually whenever a server crashes is not acceptable. Any idea how to block this, or in general how to run things "forever" ?

`screen` is really useful command, but it does not make sense if it dies when a server restart.

Comment: If you want to run it forever use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Comment: What is the diference beetwen forever and screen? As I understood they would do more or less the same thing.